# sparql query for drug interactions.minor error

Tags: java, sparql, semantic-web

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX drugbank: <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/> 

SELECT ?Drug ?IntDrug ?IntEffect 
WHERE {    
    ?Int drugbank:interactionDrug1 ?Drug .    
    ?Int drugbank:interactionDrug2 ?IntDrug .
    ?Int drugbank:text ?IntEffect .
}
```

I am running this query on endpoint `linkedlifedata.com/sparql`. How do I modify it to get the result for 2 specific drugs(drug-names) instead of all combinations of drugs.

Answer (score 1):

To query about a specific RDF resource in a SPARQL query, just add the identity of the resource to the query. You can name the resource either in `<...>` angle brackets, or in `prefix:name` format. I picked a couple of drug resources from the results of your query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX drugbank: <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/> 
PREFIX drugbank-drug: <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugs/>

SELECT ?IntEffect 
WHERE {    
    ?Int drugbank:interactionDrug1 drugbank-drug:DB01203 .    
    ?Int drugbank:interactionDrug2 
               <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/drugbank/resource/drugs/DB00414> .
    ?Int drugbank:text ?IntEffect .
}
```

This query will list all of the interaction effects for just those two drugs. In this case, that's only one interaction.